# Private subversion server that also provides a mailing list

Tags: svn, hosting

Can anyone recommend a hosting company that offers private subversion hosting over https as well as a mailing list for collaboration?

Thanks.

Edit: By "mailing list", I mean a list-serv, like something driven by GNU Mailman.  Not email notifications of subversion commits.  My main problem is that there are tons of places that offer subversion hosting, but I can't seem to find one that also offers a mailman interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for the record, I finally did find a paid host that explicitly mentions providing subversion and mailman: http://www.webfaction.com/services/hosting

This took a lot more searching than I expected, and I haven't found any alternatives for pricing comparison yet.. I suppose setting up svn on a regular hosting account is the main alternative, but I was specifically looking for something that takes care of administrative stuff like that.  I basically just want to pay for a private version of SourceForge, but nothing like that seems to be available.

Answer (score 3):

assembla.com could be an option for svn as well as GIT repositories.

Comment: **Note:** You can have only one private repo though.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [a2hosting](http://www.a2hosting.com/services/web-hosting/) also provides subversion, git, and a mailing list powered by [phplist](http://www.phplist.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I like [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/pricing) - it has reasonable pricing structure and can grow with your needs

Comment: Thanks, hadn't come across that one yet, but it doesn't look like they provide mailing lists.

Comment: Also they have "Web Hooks" feature so you can probably figure out some sort of trigger using PHP

Comment: Ah, by "mailing list" I meant like a mailman-driven email discussion group, also called a listserv.  You know, like you get on SourceForge.  Sorry, it hadn't even occurred to me to that you might consider email notifications a "mailing list".