# create private repository in googlecode

Tags: svn, google-code

How do I create a private svn repository in googlecode.

Comment: so goodbye googlecode

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not possible. From the [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/FAQ):

> All open source developers. If you plan to start an open source project, we encourage you to create a project on Google Code.

there is however an [issue in the issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=1829) about introducing commercial hosting.

Some private hosting providers can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964249/private-subversion-server-that-also-provides-a-mailing-list).

Comment: Also see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_software_hosting_facilities

Answer (score 3):

Disabling tabs does not really help, because one can always use link like:
`https://code.google.com/[project-name]/source/browse/`.

On the other hand deleting project will make it private for several days (and then can be undone). Just don't forget to undelete :D.