# How can I make my source code invisible to others?

Tags: android, svn, google-code

I am an android developer and recently using SVN to maintain my source code and uploaded my code on code.google.com . But I noticed that the code is accessible to all persons . I want that, my source code will only visible to me and the user that is created by me.

Comment: No private repository allowed on code.google.com. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4826831/833647. So, don't upload it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a private repository. As you may also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826799/create-private-repository-in-googlecode), your project must be open source in order to be hosted in google code.
 However you can host your project in different providers, such as [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) that provides private repositories for free. Unfortunately though in bitbucket there is no svn, only git and mercurial. The choice is yours!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend BitBucket with git. That's what I use along gitHub. You can have private repositories. Git is easy to pick up in hours.

Other option could be Assembla. You can have one private repo for free.

Or you can pay for private repos.